# Can I maintain the health of the data on a NAND USB drive with a power-only USB charger?

Tags: flash, usb-device

I want to maintain some data securely (avoid bit rot) on solid state media.

I know that SLC flash is the best technology to do that with, but even SLC eventually drains.

Could I plug an SLC USB flash drive into a USB charger to maintain the bits?  Or do the bits have to be rewritten every so often to prevent them from rotting?

Comment: Since leakage is exponential with temperature, an unplugged SLC device at room temperature will hold data for a very long time.  Limited endurance is only a problem for devices soldered to hot PCBs.

Comment: Can you be specific with what you mean by "a very long time"?  I'm looking for human lifetime+ storage ideally.

Comment: NAND cell endurance is tested by heating them up and measuring how long until they fail.  If you extrapolate backwards, a cell rated for 5 years at 80C lasts centuries at room temperature.  However, I'm not sure how reliable that extrapolation is going to be over such long time periods.  There are probably temperature independent failure mechanisms too.

Comment: @GordonFogus For that length of time, you should study the research done by librarians. About a decade ago, they took on the task of comparing many media types including various magnetic and electronic ones. I know that they looked at various CD ROM types (there are a number of them) and DVD ROM types (again, a number of them.) They also wanted about 100 yrs retention. I believe they found that one or two types of DVD ROMs, kept under very careful humidity and temperature circumstances, *might* be adequate. They then pointed to "paper" and found that always easily made it for many centuries.

Comment: @GordonFogus There was a system produced for distributing code in magazines, back in the 1980's: [Cauzin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauzin_Softstrip). That will keep for a very long time. I think there are newer techniques for encoding onto paper using laser printers to produce it. If you encode data with sufficient added check bits, so that the occupation of the hypercube vertices are sparse enough, I think you could get a high probability of recovering all the data a century later and more.

Comment: Thanks.  I was looking at the [Swissbit SLC U-500k series drives](https://www.swissbit.com/en/products/nand-flash-products/usb-products/) which are rated for 10 years @ life begin and 1 year at life end with a storage range of -40C to 85C. I believe "life end" meant after the endurance limit of 3216 terabytes written (seq write 128KB) for the 32GB version. Do you think that this qualifies as a good media for multi-decade storage? They are about $55 for the 2GB version. And thank you for the other suggestions--I will look into them.

Comment: @GordonFogus - You also must consider that the storage device will eventually become obsolete and it will be difficult to find a system to read it. I have a 5 inch floppy from 1980, but nothing to read it. I recommend: multiple copies, verify every 10 years, move to new storage devices every 20 years or so, depending on how fast technology advances.

Comment: @GordonFogus *Quality* paper is the known quantity for truly long term storage. There's nothing else that can compete with it. We have fragments dating over 2000 years old and still readable, for example. (And not kept well, either.) "*Other than archival ink used on archival paper in sealed storage, no current medium is proven to last an average 100 years without any sort of maintenance.*" Paper is the medium of choice for long term storage. Full stop. Librarians care about this stuff. They've looked into it. That's their result. Nothing has been proven reliable. Get used to the idea.

Comment: @GordonFogus I found [this site](http://ollydbg.de/Paperbak/) as an option to consider. Also see [here](https://hydra.wikinaut.de/bhntwiki/index.php/BHNT67/Paperback). (Sehen Sie auch [hier](https://hydra.wikinaut.de/bhntwiki/index.php/BHNT67/Paperback), wenn Sie Deutsch sprechen.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latter; don't confuse flash with SRAM or DRAM; keeping it powered has no advantage to its memory retention.

Also: if you're using a higher-quality memory device, I'd expect bit errors to appear years in the future - I'd much more expect a continuously powered device to fail earlier with a higher probability for any other reason!

Comment: Wow! That seems terrifying. So, old OS installs on SSDs? Unless those files get re-written, they will get corrupted? Does reading a "somewhat stale bit" trigger a "re-up"? I'm aiming for a lifetime storage solution outside of cloud storage and without the need to rotate hardware. Maybe that's not possible yet.

Comment: Wait, but server class SSDs are supposed to have ratings that are only a few weeks long: https://www.extremetech.com/computing/205382-ssds-can-lose-data-in-as-little-as-7-days-without-power - " In worst-case scenarios or high storage temps, the data on an enterprise drive can start to fail within seven days." But SSD servers don't seem to fail ever few weeks.

Comment: The article exaggerates. Also, the difference is that in a data center, things are at a controlled temperature, full stop - data retention at 50°C doesn't matter at all if you guarantee everything stays at 20°C at all times. This has little to do with your stick.

Comment: And that's similar to the point I'm making: what kills your data are external factors more than flash cell discharge. Speaking in pictures: if you store your flash drive in your desk, hot coffee is more likely to kill data than charge migration. If you store it plugged into a charger, that won't help data retention, and heat and electric transients over years just increase your failure probability

Comment: Thank you, that helps a lot. So, the whole "powered off" thing in the article title is somewhat misleading--it's really just a comparison of two different temperature zones for drives: one while the drive is powered on and one while the drive is powered off? So, it really just comes down to temperature + time (assuming equal humidity, vibration, and ignoring electrical transients, etc.)?